# I have this major stress...can you help me out?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, kufr, waswasa, kuffar

Aoa

So just a few minutes ago i got this thought of " reciting dhikr is doing magic " and i don't believe in it but i actually laughed as soon as i laughed i realised " wtf did i just do? " i got super depressed and fr this just happened like few minutes ago so I'm stressed that whether this is kufr or not? Like i don't believe its magic " ASTAGFIRULLAH " but i laughed at it...i mean i tried not to but did it anyway? Please help me out here...and please don't delete my question you guys have done this many times...it's starting to piss me off..please answer

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. I will first say that thoughts are of two types one comes from within yourself and the other comes from an outside source (waswasa, shayateen, etc.). Furthermore, I will say that the backbone of Islam is in this hadith

> I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) saying, "The reward of deeds depends upon the intentions and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended. So whoever emigrated for worldly benefits or for a woman to marry, his emigration was for what he emigrated for." (Bukhari in the chapter of revelation).

So with that being said you should ask yourself why you laughed and what was the reason. There are only two options, one is that you laughed at the idea because it was ridiculous and that can never be true. The other you laughed because it was funny because you had some level even 1% that you joined magic and dhikr together. If the latter I would suggest you renew your shahadah again.

**Have a nice day!**

Comment: Welp...i laughed at it.....becuase it was funny...but i don't believe in it......so yeah I'm good thanks tho and btw it's night here " have a nice night "

Comment: Yea the main thing is the intention when you had laughed at that time. 

Lol. alright have a nice night then.